# getting status code from resource with No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header present

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, xmlhttprequest, cors

I'm using good 'ol `XMLHttpRequest` to make a GET request to https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME. My goal is to confirm that a the instagram username entered by my user actually exists, and it would be great if I could confirm this on the client side.

For instance, try to make a GET request to https://www.instagram.com/9gag and you get a 200 back. https://www.instagram.com/sakjafkhdsafd and you get a 404 back.

Now, now... seems like Instagram does not allow CORS... because when I run `XMLHttpRequest.send()` I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.instagram.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Ok, guess the server is going to have to take care of this... BUT! if I check my network tab, I actually see that the request is being made and I am getting a response back with the expected status code. I also get all the html, everything. What the...?

How is it that the browser (chrome in my case) is able to capture this but not my application?

Adding my code as requested:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET", "https://www.instagram.com/" + username, false);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
           // do something...
        }
    }
xhr.send()
```

EDIT:

I just tested this on Firefox and I get a 301 back. I guess my question now is "what is chrome doing to get the expected status code on the network tab?"

Comment: Testing here. In my case all is returning a 301 http status code. Can you post your xmlHttpRequest code here?

Comment: @BrunoPeres - added to the question. I'ts just a simple raw xmlhttprequest, synchronous, but I don't think that should change anything

Comment: I just ran that code in chrome's console substituting `username` by "9gag" and got a 200 back on the network tab

Comment: to confirm that a instagram username exists is not enough to verifiy the status code == 200 into `onreadystatechange`? I believe I did not understand your problem very well. Cant you post more details about? Sorry.

Comment: @BrunoPeres I actually do not get the status code within my application. I only see the status code on the network tab of chrome whenever I make the request, and I can't understand how I'm able to get the status code within the browser from a resource that doesn't allow cors. On another note, I tested this with Firefox and I get a 301 back.

Comment: Tryng here. You can try with a switchUser like in firefox...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128767/discussion-between-bruno-peres-and-jgozal).

Answer (score 0):

Although the browser has successfully retrieved content, it is forbidding you to read any of it due to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

CORS is a little confusing in itself - if the server was okay fulfilling the request, why does the browser block it? But okay, that's a security restriction that was pasted on in a backward-compatible way.

What is more surprising is that this is true even for errors: the server must add a special header to its response even to allow the client to read a status code or error message!

But the browser will display those in the browser console and network tab.